# NSScrollView scroll bar draws on top of all views

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have two overlapping views.

- An NSTableView (the list of songs), I'll call it the **table view**
- A layer backed NSView (for the play controls at the bottom), I'll call it the **play controls view**

I was using layer backed views to render the table view previously and this caused the scroll bar to render behind the play controls view, great! But as I loaded up the table view with 150+ rows of data the app slows down pretty bad as I scroll.

I changed `setWantsLayer:` to `NO` and now the table view is much snappier, great! But now the scroll bar seems to render on top of the play controls view.

**Good:**

[image]

**Bad:**

[image]

Any ideas whats going on here? (I'm a core animation rookie if you can't tell)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you resize the entire scrollview and put the play controls view below the list? It seems by your sceenshot that the play controls view is a subview of the scrollview. Is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the entire `scrollVIew` could be a solution, but you might as well set the `scrollIndicatorInsets`:

```
yourTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets   = NSEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomValue, 0);
```

Here bottomValue would be something like 50 -150, depending on the height of your view, you might have to test this, but this will do the trick.

Edit: I just see you are working on `OSX`, my solution works on `iOS`, i hope the `NSEdgeInsetsMake` works on Max OSX similar to `UIEdgeInsetsMake` does on `iOS`.